# What is the best way to allow/deny users to perform specific activites?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use built-in ASP.NET membership mechanism but it seems not enough to me. It only allows people to do a bunch of tasks(roles). I can allow a person but it seems hard to deny one ie; allow people in accounting dept. to see sensitive info but how to deny a specific person from that dept.? I have to create AccountDept and AccountDeptNoSensitiveData roles and so on... If there are many activities than it will be a mess.

Old classic Groups and Users with Allow/Deny mechanism is much better in my situation. However I don't want to reinvent something already invented before if any and that's what I'm asking for here:

For forms based authentication, is there any extended variant of ASP.NET Membership mechanism or another good "framework/boilerplate/readymade" which one allows me to authorize/deny people to do tasks in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Claims-based authorization may be what you're looking for. Instead of a user having a particular role and all authorization that comes with the role, the user instead carries a claim, which can enable much more granular allow/deny checks.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.claimsprincipalpermission):

> This enables far more granularity than is available through pure RBAC
>   (role-based access checks), where many permissions are typically
>   collected under a single role. Perhaps, more importantly, claims-based
>   authorization enables better separation of business logic and
>   authorization policy because permission can be demanded for a specific
>   action on a resource in code and back-end policy can be used to
>   configure which claims the presenting entity must possess in order to
>   satisfy the demand.

Here's a pretty good podcast from .NET Rocks to get acquainted with the topic: [Dominick Baier Walks Us Through Claims-Based Security!](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=674).

In ASP.NET 4.5 the core framework is equiped to do claims based authorization when using forms authentication with the `System.Security.Claims` namespace. The `Page.User` object can be cast to a [`ClaimsPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal). You can inspect the principal's claims and make decisions based on it, i.e. whether to allow a certain action to be performed or not. See [`ClaimsAuthorizationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager) for a description of how this is done in ASP.NET.

Your code might get more complex, but it should be less of an administrative headache then trying to match all possible authorization combinations in multiple role definitions.

Comment: It was my understanding that claims was more focused at authentication than authorisation. It's been a while since I last looked into claims though, so I'm going go do just that.

Comment: @SimonHalsey I added a link to the ClaimsAuthorizationManager class, which explains in more detail how you can authorize resources based on claims.

Comment: hmmm. ClaimsAuthorizationManager does at least have a checkaccess method, but it still seems you need some sort of api to bind rights to roles. Even the example shown only uses group or role membership to determine access. Again I'm not totally familiar with WIF, but it appears to be just another way to do what I've said below, but in a federated way.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is a missing piece which is the next level down - rights or operations. Authorization Manager has these, but there is no native API for it. Using the AzMan com-based API is evil.

In essence, when you want to do something, you check if the user has a given right. These rights are collected in roles to which you assign users. This gives you granular fine-grained control over what roles can do, without having millions or roles.

Sadly, I'm not aware of anything out there that gives you a "rights API". I created my own one for my apps & most apps I've looked seem to roll their own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can continue to use built-in ASP.NET Membership provider and use Roles as Groups and stop asking "is user in role" anymore:

```
 User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Roles.IsUserInRole(user, role)
```

Instead I could add Tasks list and Permissions list like below:

```
 Tasks
    Task1    name="Accounting"
       Allow roles="Accounting", "Executive"
       Allow users="SalesPerson1", "OtherPerson2" //Granted people
       Deny  users="AccountingPerson1" //Banned person
```

And ask for user's permission

```
  User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && MyCustomSecurity.HaveRight(user, task)
```

Ok, somebody already did what I mention:

http://permissionmanager.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there are basically 2 approaches to allow/deny users to access resources or to perform specific activities.

1. Disable everything or forbid everything (all the controls or components), and then grant access via permission to open possibilities. This way is most secure way, user will not be able to do anything unless he/she has been granted for that action.
2. Allow everything by default, and then assign restrictions to forbid or disable actions. this is faster way, you need to create fewer restrictions by means of permissions in this case

ASP.net membership is a feature which is bit restricted in terms of granularity, security, auditing of actions, etc., still you can extend it if time is not constraint.